# Using C# ternary operator in ASP.NET grid view

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

How can we insert two different JavaScript functions based on C# ternary operator in ASP.NET grid view?
I'am using this code in a `div` tag:

```
onclick='<%#(Eval("file").ToString()=="0" ? "#" : "javascript:openPopup('Staff Report file.aspx?Id=("Id")')")%>'
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code sample rather than retyping it here! Otherwise, you're likely to introduce typos which will make your problem more difficult to solve. For example, do you have `on click` (wrong) or `onclick` (correct), and `java script` (wrong) or `javascript` (right)

Comment: I would strongly advise to you manipulate the data into what should be displayed onto the UI in code *before* binding the data, so that the data binding has to do nothing more than stick the data into the UI without manipulating it.  While there are some tools available to you, it's *much* easier to do in "real" code than when data binding.

Comment: So What is your problem? did you get any error?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that I support @Servy 's advice, in my humble opinion what you are trying to do is correct.

The problem you are facing is most likely related to the use of the string delimiters.

Try this:

```
onclick='<%#(Eval("file").ToString()=="0" ? "#" : "javascript:openPopup(\'Staff Report file.aspx?Id=(\"Id\")\')")%>'
```

Appart from that, notice that you don't usually use string delimiters inside the query string of an url, so unless you have a specific need for those quotes around `("Id")` you just don't use them like in here: `"javascript:openPopup(\'Staff Report file.aspx?Id=Id)\')"`

Besides, it's not really clear if you wanted the value for the `Id` key in the query string to be the string `"Id"`, the string `Id` or whether `("Id")` is another local or global variable defined/assigned in another part of your code, representing the real Id.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks For ur valuable rply..

```
onclick='<%#(Eval("file").ToString()=="0" ? "#" : "javascript:openPopup(\'Staff Report file.aspx?Id=(\"Id\")\')")%>'
```

Here am Passing Query String in Script like as

```
onclick='<%#(Eval("file").ToString()=="0" ? "#" : "javascript:openPopup(\'StaffReportfile.aspx?Id=(<%# Eval("Id") %>')")%>'
```

my js

```
function openPopup(strOpen) {
  open(strOpen, "StaffReportfile", 
           "status=1, width=550, height=600, top=100, left=300");
}
```

its possible two Server tag in single argument... Else how can we call it.. 
Solve me plz